# Does “ein paar” require genitive or dative?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, grammatical-case

> Ein paar intelligenter Leute sind hierher gekommen.

or

> Ein paar intelligenten Leuten sind hierher gekommen.

Comment: Neither nor. _Ein paar_ is treated like a number and doesn't affect the case at all.

Comment: Keins von beiden ist korrekt.

Comment: So what would be the correct way to say this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, *ein paar* works as if it were a number. Compare the following:

> Ein paar *intelligente* Leute wohnen hier.
>
> Wir gedenken ein paar *intelligenter* Leute.
>
> Ich bringe ein paar *intelligenten* Leuten Tee.
>
> Ich begrüße ein paar *intelligente* Leute.

As you can see, the case can be any of the four and is governed by the position of the entire phrase, *not* by *ein paar*.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is:

> Ein paar intelligente Leute sind hierher gekommen.

Comment: So, I deduce that "ein paar" is not a preposition :)

Comment: yes. However one can construct a sentence with "intelligenteR".

Comment: »Das ist das Werk intelligenter Leute.«

Comment: "ein paar" is an indefinite numeral as "einige, wenige, viele.

Answer (score 4):

Your sentences are wrong, but you can make two correct sentences out of it with different meanings, just by applying very small changes:

> Ein Paar intelligenter Leute ist hierher gekommen.
>   A pair of intelligent people did come here.

The uppercase P at Paar turns »some« into »a pair« (meaning: two who belong together). But since you have just one pair that builds the sentences subject, you have to use the singular for the verb (»ist« instead of »sind«).

»Intelligenter Leute« is like »roter Rosen« in »Ein Strauß roter Rosen«. It tells you, of what the pair is made. You can ask for the intelligent people with »wovon« (»of what«):

> Ein Paar *[wovon?]* ist hierher gekommen.

---

> Ein paar intelligente Leute sind hierher gekommen.
>   Some intelligent people did come here.

Here (with lowercase p at paar) »ein paar« means »some«, and this is treated like any number that is different from *one*:

> **Sieben** intelligente Leute sind hierher gekommen.
>   **Einige** intelligente Leute sind hierher gekommen.
>   **Mehrere** intelligente Leute sind hierher gekommen.
>   **Viele** intelligente Leute sind hierher gekommen.
>   **Ein paar** intelligente Leute sind hierher gekommen.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that while the first meaning is the original one from which the second is derived (in analogy to the younger English *couple* ambiguity), the second is so common nowadays that the first would not necessarily be understood as intended when spoken. In most contexts one would automatically 'correct' the ending of *intelligenter* to fit lower case *paar*.