# Is it "seit ein paar Tagen" or "seit einen paar Tagen"?

Tags: preposition, dative

I am aware that *seit* is a dative preposition. But I read in a book "seit **ein** paar Tagen" instead of "seit **einen** paar Tagen".

Why is that if *seit* is a dative preposition?

Comment: Is "einen" dative?

Comment: @Eller "einem" would be dative and would still be wrong.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/wie-viele-sind-ein-paar and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25752/does-ein-paar-require-genitive-or-dative and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31606/warum-ist-das-mal-in-ein-paar-mal-singular and...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"*Ein*" is a part of "*ein paar*" and "*ein paar*" is an unchangeable pronoun. That is why "*ein*" is not changed to "*einem*". Note that "Tagen" **is** dative.

If you would use "*einige*" or "*wenige*" (synonyms of "ein paar") they would take their respective dative forms - "*seit **einigen**/**wenigen** Tagen*".

PS. Don't confuse "ein paar" with "ein Paar". The latter is a substantive (a pair, a couple) and "ein" can change (*mit einem Paar Schuhe - with a pair of shoes*).

Comment: You can see this in the following sentences: *Ein paar Leute diskutieren* (Nominative). *Ich sehe ein paar Leute* (Akkusative). *Ich esse mit ein paar Leuten* (Dative). **But**: *Ein Paar Schuhe ist nicht genug* (Nominative). *Ich kaufe ein Paar Schuhe* (Accusative). *Ich laufe in einem Paar Schuhe* (Dative).

Answer (score 4):

This is correct:

> Seit ein paar Tagen.

This is half correct:

> Seit eine**m** **P**aar Tagen.

This is wrong:

> Seit einen paar Tagen.

---

Let's talk about »Seit eine**m** **P**aar Tagen.« first:

You are right, »seit« asks for a dative object. But the dative of the indefinite article »ein« is not »einen« but »einem« or »einer«:

> Seit einem Jahr. (neuter: das Jahr, ein Jahr)
>   Seit einem Monat. (male: der Monat, ein Monat)
>   Seit einer Woche. (female: die Woche, eine Woche)

So if there was any period of time which comes in pairs, you could say:

> Seit einem Paar Xxx.

(»ein Paar« with uppercase P in »Paar« is »a couple« or »a pair«. »Paar« is a noun here: Das Paar = the couple.)

Like in

> Mit **einem Paar Schuhe** habe ich nicht genug.
>   **One pair of shoes** is not enough for me. (Literally: »I don't have enough with one pair of shoes.«)

But there is no period of time that comes in couples or pairs, and this is why this construction still is wrong. (Just the case of the article was correct).

---

»Ein paar« (with lower case »paar«) means »some«:

> In der Dose sind noch **ein paar** Kekse.
>   There are **some** cookies in the jar.

So when you want to say »since some days« than you use »seit ein paar Tagen«:

> My car doesn't start any more **since some days.**
>   Meine Karre springt **seit ein paar Tagen** nicht mehr an.

And »ein paar Tagen« is still in dative case.